# Selenium WebDriver - Element is not clickable at point

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an automation project using Selenium WebDriver in version 3.6 and the Chrome Driver. The software was working fine until it started to display the error

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click
>   Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to
>   continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
>
> unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (25, -9)   (Session
>   info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763
>   (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64).

I'm using the .click () method to click on the element, and this always worked, I've never had any problems with the software running for months

Searching the internet I found methods that even worked like using .SendKey () and IJavaScriptExecutor to give a scroll to the element. But the point is I never had to do this ..

Could it be some bug in this version of Selenium? Maybe Chrome Driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by having Chrome version 61+ and not using the latest ChromeDriver.

Download the latest [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) (2.3.2) which "Fixes a bug where Chromedriver fails to click due to page scrolling changes in Chrome 61+".

Comment: Great, glad to help!